# PHP: Please help explain these ternary operators

Tags: php, operators, elvis-operator

Can anyone explain this operator please? I realise its now deprecated in 7.4 so refactoring.

This example:

```
if ($this->interestAreas()->count() > 0) {
    $ids ?: $ids = $this->interestAreas()->pluck('id');
    $this->interestAreas()->detach();
}
```

I understand it when `?:` is used assigning a variable eg: `$newUser = ($user) :? null;` but not as above. Can anyone explain how that may be rewritten?

Comment: It has the same meaning, except they're not using the result in an assignment.

Comment: It's just a shorthand for an `if` statement.

Comment: What makes you say this is deprecated?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - I got this error for similar uses in app, but maybe this use is valid actually... `Unparenthesized `a ?: b ? c : d` is deprecated`.

Comment: 7.4 deprecated nested ternaries without parentheses. That's unrelated to the elvis operator.

Comment: Ah! Easily fixed then. Its been a long day! Thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine `?` and `:` as conditional variables, a string like

```
$a = 1 ? $b : $c;
```

can be read like:

```
If $a equals 1 then show $b, if not show $c;
```